# Should I use separate javascript files or just one big files in Electron desktop app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dom, electron

I am using Electron with plain javascript to make a single page desktop app, it is a logging tool, which will receive time series data via socket from a local program (like a backend, but not a remote web backend, so I don't think the bandwidth will be the issue), and use javascript charting library to present the data in high speed.

The main data flow is like this:
socket->array->draw charts
socket->other UI update commands

Although this is a single page app, it has many components, so putting all the codes into one file makes the project difficult to extend or maintain, I wonder if I should use a OOP way to separate the codes into multiple javascript files, like what we usually do in C#. But I have no idea whether this is a good practice or not, will it incur significant performance overhead? Same concern goes to the use of TypeScript, I feel like using it instead of plain javascript, but not sure if it will slow down the app.

One more question, I use jQuery to access Dom, for example, `$chartDiv = $('#chartDiv')`, compared to `document.getElementById()`, does the overhead of using the former just happen in the first time, or it happen every time I use `$chartDiv`?

Comment: No real performance overhead. Have you considered something like react.js? Even if not, I would definitely have separate files for UI control, database/server interaction, and so on

Comment: `$chartDiv = $('#chartDiv')` and then using `$chartDiv` everwhere is more efficient than using `$('#chartDiv')` everywhere

Comment: Overhead from separate files should be minimal. Especially if you have the option to use cashing. I never used typescript, but according to the tag it compiles to normal JavaScript so shouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: thanks for the helps : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer most of your questions: do what makes the code better, not "faster". If you were seriously concerned about performance, you would be writing your app in C or assembly. Electron on its own is already causing a lot of slowdown – it's a browser running an interpreted language, evaluating CSS and HTML, what did you expect?

The entire reason for things like Electron is because it makes development easier, in particular to people who are familiar with web technologies already.

So:

- Yes, split your app into files. There may be some overhead if you don't use a transpiler / uglifier, but this is relatively tiny and only has to happen at application load time.
- Yes, use TypeScript. It is a transpiled language that only adds type safety to your code at compilation time – the additional information is stripped away after compilation, producing "vanilla JS".
- If you are doing a lot of DOM manipulation and you are familiar with jQuery, then go ahead. In modern browsers (including Electron), you don't really have to be concerned about various features not working, so most DOM manipulation that you would want is [trivial without jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Nevertheless, it is once again a relatively tiny slowdown. And `el = $('some selector')` produces most of the "slowdown" only once.

One more thing – if you are seriously concerned about your performance (personally I doubt this will be an issue), then your best bet is to profile your app! Run tests with different implementations, see which is faster, quantify performance speedups. But keep in mind:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%
>
> – Donald Knuth

Comment: Thanks Aurel, the answer is thorough and helpful!